# Why am I not able to style the table I am referring to?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

1st problem that I have is that I'm not styling the table I am referring to as "tb2". Notice that I made a distinction between the two tables by calling the first table "tb1" and the other "tb2", so I dont get why both are affected.

2nd problem that I have is that table border is not 10px solid green as I declared. Can that be because the border in "tb1" (that I am not even referring to in the code) is conflicting with the new border that I am trying to make?

If anybody can solve this mystery, please, I need your help! I'm stuck!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #tb2 table {border:10px solid green;}
            tr {background-color:black;}
            th {color:white;}
            td {border:5px dotted red;color:white;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="tb1" border="5" 
        width="50%" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
        <tr><th colspan="3"><h2>Fruit!</h2></th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Strangers</th>
            <th>Friends</th>
            <th>Family</th>
        </tr>
            <td>Lemon</td>
            <td>Pear</td>
            <td>Blueberry</td>
        </tr>
            <td>Plum</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Strawberry</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="tb2">
        <tr><th colspan="3"><h2>Fruit!#2</h2></th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Strangers</th>
            <th>Friends</th>
            <th>Family</th>
        </tr>
            <td>Lemon</td>
            <td>Pear</td>
            <td>Blueberry</td>
        </tr>
            <td>Plum</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Strawberry</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS selector is wrong. The table has an id of `tb2` so there's no reason to have the word `table` in your selector. It should just be `#tb2` The only way your current selector would work would be if you had a containing element around the table with the id of `tb2`.

Comment: Yea just remove the "table" after the #tb2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#tb2 {border:10px solid green;}
tr {background-color:black;}
th {color:white;}
td {border:5px dotted red;color:white;}
```

since element "#tb2" is applied directly to your table you do not need to specify "table"

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are using `#tb2 table` will select all tables inside the element with the `id` of "tb2". In your case, you are wanting `table#tb2` which will select all tables with the `id` of "tb2".

As far as semantics go, you could remove the `table` from the selector, since `id`s ideally only refer to one element on the page. That would leave you with `#tb2` as your selector.

**Update:** This will reflect an easier implementation of what you were looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/hzdxL18h/2/

```css
#tb1 {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border-spacing: 3px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
#tb1 td, #tb1 tr, #tb1 th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#tb2 { border: 10px solid green; }
#tb2 tr { background-color: black; }
#tb2 th { color: white; }
#tb2 td { border: 5px dotted red; color: white; }
```

```
    <body>
  <table id="tb1">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        <h2>Fruit!</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Strangers</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
      <th>Family</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lemon</td>
      <td>Pear</td>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plum</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Strawberry</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="tb2">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        <h2>Fruit!#2</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Strangers</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
      <th>Family</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lemon</td>
      <td>Pear</td>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plum</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Strawberry</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: But as you can see I have two distinctive table names: one is "tb1", the other "tb2". If I want to change just "tb2" and not "tb1", how do I do it? As my code states, I dont want green border, black background, and so on, on both tables, I just want it on "tb2". What is the problem that's causing both to change their appearance when I just want one of them modified?

Comment: As my answer states `#tb2` would select only the id of "tb2".  This will not select a different id, in your case "tb1".

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer use ids for javascript, and work out styles with classes. So then try using class="tb2" instead of id="tb2". Also, I am not sure if you can style an element using #tb2 **table** I think you need to omit one or the other in there. I tried this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tb1  {border:10px solid green;}
    tr {background-color:black;}
    th {color:white;}
    td {border:5px dotted red;color:white;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="tb1" border="5" 
    width="50%" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
    <tr><th colspan="3"><h2>Fruit!</h2></th></tr>`
```

Or you can also try:

```
 <style type="text/css">
        #tb1  {border:10px solid green;}
        tr {background-color:black;}
        th {color:white;}
        td {border:5px dotted red;color:white;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tb1" border="5" 
    width="50%" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
    <tr><th colspan="3"><h2>Fruit!</h2></th></tr>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you all for your super quick replies!:) Cant believe I was so blind! However, I still dont get why both tables are styled when I only reffer to one of them:/ Any idea?

Comment: @Deezhan What do you mean by "both tables are styled when I only refer to one"?

Comment: @Deezhan Right now only the `tr`, `th` and `td`s should be styled, the 10px border won't exist on either table since there aren't any elements that match that selector. Additionally, your CSS for the `tr`, `th` and `td` will affect both tables because you're not specifying which table ID to target in those rules.

Comment: It did show one 10px solid green border on one of the tables, but not the other one, the on that already had a border. Anyway, I solved the mystery before I managed to read your comment. I "simply" gave all tr's, th's, td's an ID, and it worked.

Comment: @Deezhan You didn't need to do that. The problem is the selector specificity you used. For instance in the style rule `tr {background-color:black;}` the selector is `tr`, which references all the table rows in all the tables. If you want to style only the table rows inside table 2, you should write `#tb2 tr` for a selector. That way, the HTML didn't need to change. Read up on selector specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! Piece by piece, the puzzle was solved thanks to all of you! This is the end result that I was looking for:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #tb2 {border:10px solid green;}
            #tr2 {background-color:black;}
            #th2 {color:white;}
            #td2 {border:5px dotted red;color:white;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="tb1" border="5" 
        width="50%" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
        <tr><th colspan="3"><h2>Fruit!</h2></th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Strangers</th>
            <th>Friends</th>
            <th>Family</th>
        </tr>
            <td>Lemon</td>
            <td>Pear</td>
            <td>Blueberry</td>
        </tr>
            <td>Plum</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Strawberry</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="tb2">
        <tr id="tr2"><th id="th2" colspan="3"><h2>Fruit!#2</h2></th></tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
            <th id="th2">Strangers</th>
            <th id="th2">Friends</th>
            <th id="th2">Family</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
            <td id="td2">Lemon</td>
            <td id="td2">Pear</td>
            <td id="td2">Blueberry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
            <td id="td2">Plum</td>
            <td id="td2">Apple</td>
            <td id="td2">Strawberry</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```